# Not getting the resource of specific variation

Tags: variations, aspx, resource-files, sputility

Actually this is a double question,

## 1

I'm trying to get the right variation from the following code:

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:MyDefaultResourceFileName,MyWantedValueKey", "MyDefaultResourceFileName", SpContext.CurrentWeb.Language)
```

like that I'm always getting the value from the default resource file, but if I change the language on the SPWeb, for instance en-en, I'm not getting the key value from the MyDefaultResourceFileName.en-en.resx

**solution:**
follow [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx) and use this code for retrieve the values from right resource file:

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:MyWantedValueKey", "MyDefaultResourceFileName", (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID)
```

but if is deployed as AppGlobalResource, check [this link](http://jonlejon.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-vs-2010-and-deploying.html) and use:

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResourceFile", "MyKey")
```

---

## 2

And the second one more simple, how I get those same values in .aspx files?

**solution:** [helpful link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/01/localizing-the-sharepoint-user-interface-by-using-resource-files-sanjay-arora.aspx)

```
<%$Resources:FileName,Key%>
```

spregards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpContext.CurrentWeb.Language` always returns languages that is used for site creation, if you would like to change languages on your site dynamically you should use `Thread.CurrentCulture.LCID'.

If you would like to get this values in .aspx file, you should create module that deploys resources files to the GlobalResources folder. See [this post](http://jonlejon.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-vs-2010-and-deploying.html) how to do it.

Then in you markup you can use <%$Resources:FileName,Key%> in server tag controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! very useful. After follow the link steps, the code is working just fine but actually is, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID and the markup code is not working...

Comment: If you use <%$Resources:FileName,Key%> in server tag, you do not need to worry about Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID. The language is resolved by the system.

Comment: are you sure alex? cause is not working with me...with <%$Resources:FileName,Key%> the value show is not from Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID lang. resource but the SPContext.Current.Web.Language

Comment: I'm sure. ) see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/01/localizing-the-sharepoint-user-interface-by-using-resource-files-sanjay-arora.aspx).

Comment: of course u r right!! my fault...some conflicts with code behind. I'll follow only the markup approach. many thanks alex!